# В чем разница между причастием "реализованный" и прилагательным "реализованный"?

Tags: значение-слов, прилагательные, причастия, части-речи

В чем разница между причастием реализованный и прилагательным реализованный, кроме принадлежности к разным частям речи? Как определить часть речи этого слова в каком-либо контексте?

Answer (score 1):

Глагол ***реализовать***  двувидовой:  реализует (несов. вид) и  реализовал (сов. вид).

**От глагола несовершенного вида** образуется форма ***реализуемый***, которая при отсутствии зависимого слова в Т.п. является прилагательным.

**От глагола совершенного вида** образуется **причастие**, которое при особых условиях может утратить признак как действие и приобрести качественный признак.

Такой переход  можно рассмотреть на следующем примере:  **организованная экскурсия** ― **организованный** (собранный, надежный, внимательный) **человек**. Часто такие отпричастные прилагательные используются в **переносном значении**, имеют синонимы среди обычных прилагательных и вступают с ними в однородные отношения.

Форма "организованный" обычно является причастием: **реализованные проекты, реализованные товары.**

Но иногда встречаются примеры  **с переносным значением этого слова**:

Поэтому в цивилизованных странах законы, порядки, мораль и моду диктует средний класс ― достаточно богатые, образованные и **профессионально реализованные люди**, чувствующие свою востребованность.

**Реализованные люди**  ― сочетание с прилагательным.

Comment: Похоже, цитата из журнала "Автопилот" - уникальный случай словоупотребления: вряд ли можно "профессионально реализовать" людей ("реализованные" и здесь воспринимается как _страдательное причастие_; напрашивается "проф. реализовавшиеся").

Comment: Не совсем уникальный, вот еще один: Напротив, если реализованный мастер или святой говорит то, чего нет, то его слова материализуются: энергия, которую он пробуждает словами, столь сильна, что изменяет реальность. [Андрей Лапин. Индуистская тантра (1990-1999)] А где взять другое прилагательное, котором идет речь в разборе: http://morphologyonline.ru/реализованный

Comment: Похоже, есть такой русскоязычный индуистский термин, как "реализованный мастер" - это сочетание часто фигурирует в специальных текстах. Но за их пределами "реализованный" вместо "реализовавшегося" по отношению к человеку выглядит нескладно. Что касается ссылки, то это сетевая программа формального разбора, от которой можно ожидать любого результата.

Comment: Но вот автор вопроса уверен, что прилагательное существует, не хочется его разочаровывать. И кстати, почему вы решили, что надо "реализовать людей", ведь образовать их тоже вряд ли получится, тем не менее образованные люди встречаются. Смысл-то у прилагательных переносный.

Comment: Людям можно дать образование, но не реализацию. А вот "профессионально реализованные программы" находятся сразу (они все так или иначе реализованы или выполнены, если они есть - это не свойство). В "реализованном" всегда сквозит призрак совершённого когда-то действия (как с продукцией).

Comment: Да я не то чтобы сравниваю эти глаголы по значению,  я удивляюсь, что вы  требуете от прилагательного переходности в соответствии со словосочетанием "реализовать людей." Люди реализовали свои способности, но мы их самих условно называем реализованными.

Comment: Их называют _реализовавшимися_ или _самореализовавшимися_, "реализованные" же - терминологическая условность (кто-то когда-то так перевёл), в обычным контекстах не употребляемая.

Comment: Ваши слова плохо выговариваются,  а это существенный недостаток для современной речи. Поэтому дело не в переводе, и слово вполне может закрепиться в языке из-за удобной фонетики, просто получит расширение значения. Может быть, и "образованный человек" когда-то звучало странно.